# InputFileStream and while loop in clojure

Tags: loops, clojure

Could someone conver this code into clojure for me

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));

                // Read in first line, if nothing, inputString is null
                String inputString = br.readLine(); // First line is header
                inputString = br.readLine();
    while (inputString != null) {

        rowCount++;
    }
```

I understand the need to use recur, however, since i am reading from a file and the row count is an immutable value, how could i increment it such that the value keeps on increasing in the while loop.

Answer (score 2):

If all you need is the count of lines in the file, you can do this:

```
(defn count-lines[file]
  (with-open [r (clojure.java.io/reader file)]
  (count (line-seq r))))
```

Or, if you want to do something with each line (for example, print it):

```
(defn count-lines[file]
   (with-open [r (clojure.java.io/reader file)]
    (loop [i 1
          s (line-seq r)]
          (println (first s))
          (if (seq (rest s))
           (recur (inc i) (rest s)) i))))
```

Comment: But if i would need to use the rowCount variable for future use how would the loop be

Comment: Added an example that does something for side effects and returns the counter.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defn read-lines [file]
  (clojure.string/split-lines (slurp file)))

; count the number of lines
(count (read-lines "c:/test.log"))

; returns a list of indexed lines
(map-indexed vector (read-lines "c:/test.log"))
;[[0 "Line 1"]
; [1 "Line 2"]
; [2 "Line 3"]
;  ...]
```